# OpenTelemetry java exporter failing to authenticate over TLS even through standard libraries work

Tags: open-telemetry, otel

We're using a third party observability backend that exports multiple end points supporting various protocols for writing/reading data such as Prometheus remote read/write, Otel HTTP/Protobuf, etc. The endpoint is based on HTTPS specification and thus requires TLS.

There is no issue with reading/writing telemetry over these endpoints when a simple Java/Go framework is used. Specifically, we use a very standard configuration of Apache HTTPClient to write metrics to the endpoint.

However, recently I was giving OpenTelemetry API/SDK a go and ran into issues with TLS verification. e.g. unable to find path to a certificate needed to verify TLS, etc. I would presume the default set up would work without any overrides, similar to Prometheus (Go) or  standard Java HTTP clients. Has anyone else experienced these issues with TLS in OTel instrumentation libraries (that in turns uses okhttp for exporting signals)?

Separately, I couldn't find a way to disable TLS verification for initial testing. Is this feature not available as a configuration? Lastly, even after adding the server certificate to the client host certificate file locally and overriding the certificate (OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_CERTIFICATE), the authentication still fails.

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/sdk-configuration/otlp-exporter-configuration/
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java
https://github.com/square/okhttp

Comment: Have you create an issue about this at https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/issues for this? I am experiencing something similar.